# Some USB devices are disabled after rebooting into Windows 7 from Ubuntu (Error code 43)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, multi-boot

I have dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm facing a strange problem. Every time when I boot into Ubuntu and then come back to Windows, both my Saitek devices (X52 PRO joystick and Rudder Pedals PRO) are disabled. When I go into "devices and printers", they both are presented as "Unknown Device" and when I go into "properties" of any of these, I get message:

> Code 43: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems

I have to replug them to make them work again. It doesn't happen when I reboot from Windows and into Windows. It happens only (and always) after booting into Ubuntu.

If it's relevant, my motherboard is Gigabyte GA-990XA-UD3 rev 1.1. My BIOS is updated to latest version for this motherboard (F13).

What could be the cause (and solution) here?

Comment: As an alternative to unplugging and re-plugging, I'm assuming powering off after using Ubuntu and before booting into Windows also works?

Comment: @Karan yes, powering off works, but I have to completely remove power from PC.

Comment: Yes, as I suspected. For whatever reason your gaming devices (or the USB controllers) are being left in an unusable state as far as Windows is concerned, but a full power off resets them. Have you tried with both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports on the motherboard?

Comment: @Karan yes, same result for 3.0 and 2.0 ports. My friend's suspicion is that these devices hold a state internally that isn't reset by Linux and only powering them off completely resets this. In this case, finding Linux drivers should help.

Comment: Certainly seems that way. If you can replicate with another Linux distro then it certainly might be worth reporting to the Linux kernel mailing list, and to Saitek for sure.